# Graphql subscriptions in Nuxt

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, publish-subscribe

I am trying to set up a web socket between the Apollo server and the Nuxt client.

[Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions)  recommends using [graphql-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-ws) over [subscriptions-transport-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subscriptions-transport-ws) as the last one is deprecated.

I already have sever set up using `graphql-ws`, but nuxt is using `subscriptions-transport-ws` and they are not compatible.

Can someone provide me with an example of how to use `graphql-ws` as a plug-in in Nuxt for Graphql subscriptions?

Comment: you don't use Apollo client for your front-end ?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for Nuxt 3 with the module @nuxtjs/apollo.
If you have authentication for your WebSocket, with x-hasura-admin-secret, this is the perfect example for you :

```
import { createHttpLink, from, split } from "@apollo/client/core";
import { RetryLink } from "@apollo/client/link/retry";
import { getMainDefinition } from "@apollo/client/utilities";
import { GraphQLWsLink } from "@apollo/client/link/subscriptions";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import { provideApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import { createClient } from "graphql-ws"; // Already import with @nuxtjs/apollo module

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

    // Optional method to get headers 
    const getHeaders = (full = false) => {
        let hasura;
        const token = localStorage.getItem("x-hasura-admin-secret")
        if (token) hasura = atob(token);
        const headers = full
            ? { headers: { "x-hasura-admin-secret": hasura.trim() || null } }
            : { "x-hasura-admin-secret": hasura.trim() || null };
        
        return headers;
    }

    const envVars = useRuntimeConfig();
    const { $apollo } = nuxtApp;

    // trigger the error hook on an error
    const errorLink = onError((err) => {
        nuxtApp.callHook("apollo:error", err); 
    });

    const retryLink = new RetryLink({
        delay: {
            initial: 300,
            max: 60000,
            jitter: true,
        },
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        attempts: (count, operation, e) => {
            if (e && e.response && e.response.status === 401) return false;
            return count < 30;
        },
    });

    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
        uri: envVars.public.graphqlApi // http:// ou https://
    });

    const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
        createClient({
            url: envVars.public.graphqlWss, // wss://
            lazy: true,
            connectionParams: () => ({
                headers: getHeaders()
            })
        })
    );

    const splitLink = split(
        ({ query }) => {
            const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
            return (
                definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
                definition.operation === "subscription"
            );
        },
        wsLink,
        httpLink
    );

    $apollo.defaultClient.setLink(
        from([errorLink, retryLink, splitLink])
    );

    provideApolloClient($apollo.defaultClient);
});
```